# Bitcoin icon for .desktop file

Tags: bitcoin-core

When I run bitcoin-qt from CLI I get a nice Bitcoin icon with distinct colors for main and testnet.

[image: Bitcoin main net][image: Bitcoin testnet]

I want to create a .desktop file to run it from Gnome, how can I configure the icon to be the same?
I don't seem to find those icons on the release files to reference.

Comment: How are you installing Bitcoin Core?

Comment: I downloaded the binaries from the website and just ran from CLI `./bin/bitcoin-qt`. I also compiled the code myself and have the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the icons from the source repo at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/share/pixmaps.